# Does it make sense to run Wilcoxon rank sum test with sample size of 1 or 2?

Tags: r, nonparametric, wilcoxon-signed-rank

suppose I have the following numbers.

```
y <- c(0.378, 0.347, 0.398, 2.05, .06, .29, 1.06, .14, 1.29)

x2 <- c(.1)
wilcox.test(y,x2)

x3 <- c(.1, .2,)
wilcox.test(y,x3)
```

I'm surprised that the first example with a sample of 1 yielded a p value.  Does this p value mean anything? What about when its N=2?

thanks!

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'mean anything'.  As shown in my Answer, it is not possible to get a _significant_ P-value if the first sample has nine observations and second sample has only one observation.  For your particular choice of `x3` the P-value is not significant. However, in this case, it is possible for a second sample of size two to yield a significant result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeating your R session---with a correction and some modifications.

```
 y <- c(0.378, 0.347, 0.398, 2.05, .06, .29, 1.06, .14, 1.29)
 x2 <- c(.1)
 wilcox.test(y,x2)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

 data:  y and x2
 W = 8, p-value = 0.4
 alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

The P-value is $0.4 > 0.05,$ so there is no significant difference in
location at the 5% level.  However, with only one observation in `x1` you
will not get a significant result even if the value in `x2` is greater
than any value in `y`.

```
xx2 = c(3)
wilcox.test(y,xx2)

     Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  y and xx2
W = 0, p-value = 0.2
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

By chance alone, there are two chances in ten that the one value in `xx2` might have been the largest
or the smallest of all the observations.

```
x3 <- c(.1, .2)     $ note: extra comma deleted
wilcox.test(y,x3)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  y and x3
W = 15, p-value = 0.2182
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Again here, a non-significant P-value is computed.

The change here is that--if both values in `xx3` are extreme--then it is
possible for the P-value to be significant at the 5% level.

```
xx3 = c(3,4)
wilcox.test(y,xx3)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  y and xx3
W = 0, p-value = 0.03636
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is not equal to 0
```

By chance alone, there are 2 chances in ${11\choose 2}= 55$ that the two observations
in `xx3` would be the two largest or the two smallest out of $9+2=11,$ then $2/55 =  0.03636.$